# How to tell git ignore changes of .angular/cache/14.2.0/babel-webpack/

Tags: angular, git, github, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using visual studio code to work with an angular project.

Every time I compiled my project with `ng serve` and then `git status` to verify my changes, the changes is full of .angular/cache/14.2.0/babel-webpack/ changes and it occupies all of my terminal lines. Like this

[image]

Also under these "cache" changes, there are a path "src/app/services/" shown, I guess it helps with the answer?

How can I tell git to ignore these "cache" changes? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Create a file with name .gitignore.txt on root folder of project (same level with src folder).

Second: add this line to this file

```
/.angular/cache
```

like this:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
# misc
/.angular/cache
```

note: # tag in this file is comment

And upload .gitignore.txt file to git.

Hope this help!